# is Plivo iOS Client SDK provides outbound call record feature?

Tags: ios, plivo, call-recording

I tried to play around with the Plivo iOS sdk to for outbound calling. I read on Plivo that there are API end points which allows users to record a call, As i can not find a similar methods in their iOS sdk, I am curious if the same can be possible through iOS sdk or if someone has the idea to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by making use of the record XML element in the application associated to the endpoint that's used in the iOS App. While making outbound calls from the iOS app, you'd be using an endpoint to login to the app. This application can contain an XML doc like below:

```json
<Response>
  <Record action="https://<your_server>/get_recording/" startOnDialAnswer="true" redirect="false" maxLength="3600" />
  <Dial>
    <Number>15551234567</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Please refer to [this doc](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/xml/record#record-complete-session).

If you wish to record calls more flexibly, you can use the [Record API](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/api/call/record-calls#start-recording-a-call) too. You can check our detailed guide for [Recording](https://www.plivo.com/docs/voice/use-cases/record-calls/node).

Plivo supports XML doc generation in 7 programming languages, you can use the language you prefer and host the app and use your server URL as the Answer URL for the application that's associated with the endpoint.

Hope this helps! Feel free to contact our [support team](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) if you need any further assistance.